# Symfony lose session when I make certain requests

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, session, angular

I am working with angular 2 and I make requests for symfony only that the problem and that when I make certain requests the syfomy loses the sessions but from afar to far it works I do not know what it can be I will leave below a request that works and another That does not work if you can help me I'd be grateful

this works

```
getOneEntidade(entid:number)
{
  this.token = this.cookieService.get("auth");

  let headers = new Headers({  'Content-Type': 'text/html' , 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, body: '', withCredentials: true});    
  return this.http.get(this.urlbase + "oneentidades/" + entid , options)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());

}
```

This does not work.

```
getpesquisa(pesquisa:string,  pag:number){

  this.token = this.cookieService.get("auth");

  let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'text/html','Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, body: '', withCredentials: true});    
  return this.http.get(this.urlbase + "pesquisaentidades/" + pesquisa + "/" + pag , options)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: ".YOUR_DOMAIN"
        name: SFSESSID
        cookie_httponly: false
```